# JQuery Add An HTML Text Box

Tags: jquery, html, textbox

I am designing a note application and I'm having trouble with adding multiple notes using JQuery. The way I designed it was relatively simple, a textbox overlayed on an image of a sticky note. To generate a new note here's the code I use for the image.

```
function addEvent() {
var ni = document.getElementById('myDiv');
var numi = document.getElementById('theValue');
var num = (document.getElementById("theValue").value -1)+ 2;
numi.value = num;
var divIdName = "my"+num+"Div";
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.setAttribute("id",divIdName);
newdiv.prepend = "<img src='Sticky_Note.png'</a>";
ni.appendChild(newdiv);
var newtext = document.createElement('Note')
newdiv.prepend = "<input type="textarea" rows="3" cols="25" x-webkit-speech="x-webkit-     speech" style="width:380px;height:300px; background: none; border:none; font-size:24px; color:#0033FF;font-family:comic sans ms " />";
ni.appendChild(newtext);
```

But the textbox doesn't show up!
What should I do to fix it?

Comment: It's plain Javascript. no jQuery at all

Answer (score 0):

If that is the original code, this *might* be your problem:

```
"<input type="textarea" rows="3" cols="25" x-webkit-speech="x-webkit-     speech" style="width:380px;height:300px; background: none; border:none; font-size:24px; color:#0033FF;font-family:comic sans ms " />";
```

You use qoute inside qoute. You might want to change the " to '.

```
"<input type='textarea' rows='3' cols='25' x-webkit-speech='x-webkit-     speech' style='width:380px;height:300px; background: none; border:none; font-size:24px; color:#0033FF;font-family:comic sans ms ' />";
```

Answer (score 0):

you have an opening of an image tag (), without closing your image:

```
newdiv.prepend = "<img src='Sticky_Note.png'</a>";
```

@Dandroid already caught your quotes issue..